# Topology of uniform convergence on $C(X,Y)$ is independent of metric for compact $X$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness, uniform-convergence

I seek verification for the following (which I believe to be true):

Let $X$ be a set with fixed topology and $(Y,d)$ a metric space. $C(X,Y)$ denotes the space of all continuous functions $f: X \to Y$; we endow it with the topology of uniform convergence (t-uc). Now in general, if we change to a topologically equivalent metric $d'$ on $Y$, the t-uc on $C(X,Y)$ w.r.t. this metric might be different from the t-uc w.r.t. $d$. For this, one can find various example on this site.

My question: If it is known that $X$ is compact (e.g. a closed, bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$), then this does not happen, i.e. in this case the topology of uniform convergence on $C(X,Y)$ is invariant under changing  to different topologically equivalent metrics on $Y$, right?

I guess one argument could be as follows: For compact $X$, the topology of uniform convergence on $C(X,Y)$ coincides with the compact-open-topology on $C(X,Y)$, which, in turn, clearly depends on the topology of $X$ and $Y$ only (and not on a specific metric inducing the topology on $Y$).

In particular, when $X$ is compact and I want to show closedness of some set $A \subset C(X,Y)$ (the latter endowed with t-uc), then in doing so I may (if this should turn out to be helpful) freely choose any metric on $Y$, which generates the prescribed, fixed topology on $Y$.

Am I correct or is there a problem in the above? Thanks in advance for any comments or answers on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology of uniform convergence is the topology induced by the $\sup$-metric. This is only defined on the set $C_{bd}(X,(Y,d))$ of continous functions which are bounded with respect to $d$. However, if $d$ is a bounded metric or if $X$ is compact, then $C_{bd}(X,(Y,d)) = C(X,Y)$.

Your argument is correct: If $X$ is compact, then it is well-known that the topology of uniform convergence induced by any metric $d$ agrees with the compact-open topology.

More generally, for any $X$ the compact-open topology agrees with the topology of uniform convergence *on all compact $C \subset X$*, for any metric $d$ on $Y$.

Comment: Thanks Paul! You are right. However, it sounds like the t-uc is only defined for $Y$ being endowed with a bd. metric (if one does not want to put assumptions on $X$). But the t-uc is defined also in more general situations, e.g. for unbounded $(Y,d)$ (in this case, it might happen that $C(X,Y)$ with t-uc is not be metrizable, but still the topology is well-defined, right?). Even more, using the notion of uniform spaces, one makes sense of the t-uc without any notion of metric on $Y$. Clearly, I do not mean to say this is not clear to you - but maybe it is valuable for people reading this post.

Comment: Right, in the metric case one can define always define a closure operator on $C(X,Y)$ by saying that $f \in \overline{M}$ if there exists a sequence of $f_n \in M  \subset C(X,Y)$ such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly. See https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Topology_of_uniform_convergence.